# Expresso Store custom tax rule

Tags: expresso-store, add-on-development, extension, tax

I've worked on a few custom plugins/add-ons before but am a bit rusty on extensions. I need to write a custom tax rule for Store and looking for guidance on targeting one of the Store extension hooks, `store_order_taxes`.

I've got a simple extensions set up and installed but for some reason it does not seem to be being called or applied to the cart in the front-end.

Any suggestions?

Cole

Answer (score 2):

Sorted thanks. The issue here was a typo (store_orders_taxes not store_order_taxes).

Pro tip folk - use a different name for your method from the hook you are accessing!